# Trigger deployment job from Multibranch pipeline Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

So, we are currently using Multibranch pipeline to run our Continuous Integration process and the last stage is publish the deployable artifact in our JFrog Artifactory "dev" repository and this works!

My problem is that, if I want to automatically trigger a new Jenkins job to take that deployable artifact and deploy it into an integration server and run functional tests then I imagine I would do something like this at the end of my Jenkinfile:

```
stage("trigger artifact deployment") {
    build job: deploymentPipeline,
            parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'deployableArtifactId', value: "${name}-${version}"],
                         [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'projectName', value: name],
                         [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'projectVersion', value: version]],
                        ...
            wait: false
}
```

This approach works! However and because it's a Multibranch pipeline, I would have to hardcode the Jenkins job I want to trigger which I really rather not do but I don't know what else to try as I don't think there would be another way to get the info I need to find the artifact to deploy (ID, version, name, etc.), right?

Answer (score 0):

If you just published it to artifactory, why do you need to find it again? I would add Artifactory properties to the file on upload to enable easier retrieval again.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Properties